# How can I use AWS MSK in local development?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk

I am planning to use AWS MSK, but I am curious to know how will the local development will look like. I know that the MSK have public access, but I am looking to see if there are any other solutions I can find before going that route. I wonder if there are any docker images such as [dynamodb](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local)? If not, is there any other solution I can use?

Comment: MSK is Managed Kafka. Kafka is an open source software, is not something invented by AWS. You don't need a Docker image provided by AWS to run Kafka locally. You can use an image from the community, such as [bitnami/kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/)

Comment: Ok it is my bad. I know that Kafka is completely separate and independent software, but I thought when using MSK the connection is going to be different.

Comment: My team is trying to set up something similar. We want an "AWS MSK" like environment that we can run on our machines for local development and testing before deploying to the cloud. Our use case is a stream processing app, so some of the things we are considering are the AWS SerDe libraries and Glue schema registry to go along with that. We're still planning to use bitnami kafka for the bulk of the kafka dependencies (we use docker to spin all that up), but there are some MSK-specific considerations as I mentioned.